# Javascript preventDefault history back

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, hashtag

Is it possible to prevent the browsers history back event ?

I have a One-Page Website with Hash-Tags - when clicking on history back i want to slide to the last hash-tag position. Is there any solution ?

Comment: Don't confuse hashtags (a means to highlight a phrase for searching on Twitter and other social networks) with fragment identifiers (part of a URL).

Comment: Using fragment identifiers for a 1PS shouldn't be a barrier to the back button navigating through the fragment ids rather then previous pages. You need to show us some code.

Comment: Don't use the fragment identifiers hack. We have the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to interact with these buttons or the history back function.

**EDIT**
As I said below, you can use window.onhashchange(). Here is an example:

```
window.onhashchange = function(e) {
    //hash changed
    //yourFunction(location.hash);
}
```

There is not much to it, you can get the new hash from the location object and I guess from the event (e) as well.
Look up https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onhashchange for more detail.

Comment: For example: http://simon-k.com do the same think i want to do. How is it possible on his Website, when there is no way to interact with these buttons ?

Comment: Okay i solved the problem..i jused arncher for the hash tags ... but i need to use the /#TAG/Value syntax so the browser dont jump to the point...

Comment: Thats a good point. I thought access to anything outside of the document was banned **but**: I looked up and there is an (HTML5) event **.onhashchange** and thats what you want to use (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onhashchange?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onhashchange). BTW: Simon does not interact with these buttons, he waits until the browser changes the hash.

Comment: Yeah thats right - "interact with the browsers history back" was the wrong wording by me.

Answer (score 0):

Try This small chunk of code .

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   return "you wanna to go Back????";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Blah Blah Blah Blah
</body>
</html>
```

It will give an event if you press the back button.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
    window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
}

function isSection(section) {
    if ($('.' + section).length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function locationHashChanged() {
    var section = location.hash;
    var section = section.replace("#", "");
    if (isSection(section)) {
        SelectNavItem(section);
    }
}

function SelectNavItem(item) {
    $("nav a").removeClass("selected");
    $("[href=#" + item + "]").addClass("selected");
}
```